# How can I configure NextAuth behind Nginx in a local environment?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I hope you can help me.

Currently I'm working with a local environment with docker compose, I built a NextJS site with NextAuth. I've configured a Nginx as a proxy, but I have a problem when I try to login to my application I got the following error:

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 {
  error: {
    message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
    stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n' +
      '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'keycloak',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80'
}
```

I've tried to configure `NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://next-container:3000` and `NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000` but it doesn't work.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen \[::\]:80;
server_name test.site.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;
    
    # To allow special characters in headers
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    
    # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
    client_max_body_size 5m;
    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr; # To forward the original client's IP address
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # to forward the  original protocol (HTTP or HTTPS)
    proxy_set_header Host $host; # to forward the original host requested by the client
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://next-container:3001/;
    }
    
    location /keycloak/ {
        rewrite /keycloak/(.*) /$1  break;
    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    
    
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080/;

    }

}
```

Here is my next `.env` file:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://test.site.com
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://next-container:3001
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=some-secret

KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=my-realm
KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET=client-secret
KEYCLOAK_ISSUER=http://test.site.com/keycloak/realms/my-realm
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   test.site.com
```

I'm using Keycloak to authenticate my users, but I think it is not the problem.

Thank you for your time :)